# Creating Your own taskbar

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0

Am making my own taskbar that will appear on top of other windows. how do I make it push other windows down such that when maximised they don't overlap my taskbar

Comment: Thats called an "AppBar", see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75785/how-do-you-do-appbar-docking-to-screen-edge-like-winamp-in-wpf

Comment: You can move the Taskbar around.

Answer (score 0):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463149/wpf-window-topmost-for-own-application-only). In short, don't use [Window.Topmost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.topmost.aspx), as this will put your window above all other windows, which is just rude! Instead, set the "Owner" property of the other windows to be the window that you appear on top.

Comment: He wants to change the maximized size of windows so they don't overlap, not control what window is on top.